# Questions about the transcript of the YouTube video "Five Stages of Watching A Marvel Movie"

Tags: listening

What is the transcript at 1:04 of this video "Five Stages of Watching A Marvel Movie - HISHE Features: OnlyLeigh" (https://youtu.be/gvjMJEqkDqA)"?
It sounds like "not to mention the TV show web series 'in card game'."
I search on google but can't find other web series connected with Marvel besides "Daredevil".

Comment: "Tv show, web series **and** card game." is what it sounds like to me.

Comment: Questions? Where's another question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"... not to mention the TV show, web series **and** card game'* is what I hear.